# Logical/Scientific Explanation for Umbrakinesis?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, physics, super-powers, logic

I'm working on a story where the characters have **elemental-based powers** based on natural material/materials/phenomena found in nature. So far, each of the powers makes sense on a physical level, since their foundation is based on them being a form of matter or energy.

The problem is is that one of the characters has **umbrakinesis**. While there is a spiritual context in the story, I don't want to wave off as **'it's just magic, don't look far into it and turn your brain off'.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkness What darkness is

https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Darkness_Manipulation Examples of users

Darkness is essentially the absence of energy, in this case light. And this make the problem worse is because darkness has no mass, and **I want to make the darkness power be on equal footing with the other elemental powers whiles having a logical and scientific reason why this is possible?**

Like this Foundation allows the darkness to manipulate/push around objects, allows the darkness to manifest in naturally-lit areas and allows the user to darken the area around them too.

At the moment, I'm thinking that possibly it's explanation could be explained with the exact barrier to which light and darkness connect, forming a crude area of effect. But that's all I have so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid there is a strict one question per post rule. You will need to separate your questions. Reusing text is OK.

Comment: Removed the bullet points and rephrased them

Comment: What is the difference between what you call darkness and what I call shadow? By darkness, do you mean an area that is not emitting/reflecting any light? Also, what are you exactly expecting from an answer. I don;t think this power (and most likely the other ones you have) will actually "make sense on aphysical level" by any rigorous standard. So can you clarify what you need from an answer exaclty?

Comment: How can we provide an answer that will put umbrakinesis on the same level as the other elemental powers with no idea of what they are or what they can do?  They're probably not going to be equivalent either, I'd expect heliumkinesis to be weaker than plutoniumkinesis, for example...  More seriously, it's not even comparing apples with oranges, it's comparing apples with internet service providers.  A pyrokinetic may be the best at combat but an umbrakinetic would presumably be the best at stealth missions - which is "better" depends on context.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I understood it as "putting it at the same level *of credibility*" as the other powers, from the context of the question, not the same level of "power". Tho your comment still stands; we don't know just how far-fetched the other powers are, so we can not compare in that regard either

Comment: @BarbaudJulien I mean on terms of it not emitting light.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 When I mean on the same level, I mean it is a reliable element to use in general. That's what I mean by on the same level. my bad,

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Yes, Barbaud is correct. I'm trying to find a way to make it seem like its credible in terms of logic. I would say in terms of power... well the closet I can compare it to would be the conduits from the Infamous series? But with the power-scaling toned down a notch

Comment: @PlanetJuice your comments did not clarify your question for me, and left my questions unanswered. If you ask for a science-based answer, you're naturally gonna be expected to be much more thorough in the details you give. Please give a clear definition of what you call darkness. Your wiki takes black paint as an example in its definition of darkness. Is it really what you have in mind? Please clarify your level of expectation as well. To be blunt; your power is gonna make no sense to anyone scientifically-minded. So we need you to define the standards of what you deem logically acceptable

Comment: If you read the rollovers for the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags, you'll learn that they're *mutually exclusive.* You need to pick just one. Please enjoy the habit of reading the tag wikis before use.

Comment: Asking us to brainstorm an explanation for how your magic works isn't a good question for this site. It's your magic system and it can work however you want it to. As is explained in the [help] brainstorming and idea generation aren't permitted.

Comment: @sphennings I wasn't trying to brainstorm, I was trying to find to explain to the readers of this story of how to make umbrakinesis plausible. But I understand, I won't do it again.

Comment: @BarbaudJulien I just thought of this. My definition of darkness is the absence of light, in the context of my story. The lack of photons in a given area. I treat this factor in the same context if someone was manipulating cold for example. Since cold and heat exist on a spectrum, there would be an energy barrier of some kind to distinguish the two. I imagine this barrier would create 'friction' or 'polarity ' that would cause energy to become more compresses in some form. That is currently what I had in mind when it comes to the manipulation of light and darkness and how they're plausible.

Comment: You basically need a new physics model. This isn't impossible, Keyes did it with his Age of Unreason series... in the book, Newton masters alchemy and the physics model is based upon it. Steampunk with flying machines, a world war, and a demiurge trying to destroy humanity for some grudge that no one ever learns the details of (King Louis destroys London by nuking it with a wayward comet). By the end of the book (I don't think this is a spoiler), the physics model of the universe is changed to the Standard model we all know and love-hate. But you're not going to do this with that model.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**You're treating the absence of something as if it is, itself, something**

It ain't.

Umbrakinesis and Photokinesis are the same thing. They may not be in the magical world of superheros and supervillains, but you tagged your question *Science-Based.* Darkness is the absence of light.<sup>1</sup> The only way you get it is by manipulating the light.

*Why is this important? Because the contents of an empty glass could be described as "the absence of water." And I'm hard-pressed to believe that someone can manipulate what's in an empty glass and call it the ability to manipulate the absence of water. Kinda reminds me of Dwayne Johnson's line from* Jungle Cruise. *"The back side of water! ... It's totally different...."*

So, scientifically, an "umbrakinetic" is a photokinetic who prefers dark rooms. But it's all the same superpower. The ability to manipulate light.

And how do you do that scientifically?<sup>2</sup> Well... with gravity. Or by manipulating the atmosphere to create lenses. Or by manipulating water to create really dense clouds. Or by making everything in the area that's "dark" totally light absorbent (entirely non-reflective). That could cause some heat problems.... Or, if you really want to channel your inner Einstein, give your superhero the ability to *convert energy to mass* such that the photons drop to the ground like so many grains of sand.

That might actually make for an interesting story. Your umbrakinetic creates darkness by converting light to mass, resulting in a substantial storm of "stuff" flying about like a sandstorm. Really fine "stuff." I'd probably be allergic to it. That'd be dark on several levels.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Technically, darkness, which is something perceived by critters like humans with eyeballs, is the absence of visible electromagnetic energy. But the simplification works for the answer.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *What you're about to discover is that you can manipulate a lot of things other than light, all of which affect light. In other words, while it's certainly true that photokenisis is the opposite of umbrakenisis, the manipulation of light, itself, isn't actually the only path you can take to get to the "creation of darkness."*</sub>

Comment: I didn't think of it like that. That does make sense. Since light does have force in a sense, and converting that into 'darkness'... it would make it plausible and how the darkness can manifest in natural daylight. I guess this would be considered a variation of photokinesis?

Comment: @PlanetJuice It must, it's the light that's being manipulated. Pour the water out of that glass... are you manipulating the absence of water, or the water? Yeah... the water.

Comment: Similarly, a cryokinetic is a pyrokinetic who likes cold rooms

Comment: The amount of mass created is somewhat insubstantial: something around 0.75g of converted mass accounted for the 20 kt blast at Hiroshima, so neutralising any realistic amount of light (by creation of an appropriate number of antiphotons) will result in the creation of only a tiny amount of matter. Of course, the nature of that matter might be interesting... inconvenient... embarrassing...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd The amount of mass created is irrelevant. The Q only asks how to scientifically rationalize the superhero ability - not its consequences. In the OP's fictional world wherein superheros reside, it can be any amount wanted. However, you make a *wonderful* point about what the converted matter could be, since to the best of our understanding, it can be any matter. An author could have a ton of fun with that. Statistically, it's likely to be hydrogen... or it could be the ripe-for-worldbuilding element [astatine](https://www.livescience.com/39514-facts-about-astatine.html).

Comment: Love your answer, and it sparks an idea: The general consensus is that Umbrakinetics control the darkness itself - you turn that idea on its head and say that it is the light that's being controlled (not the first instance of a power being misunderstood in its own universe). That has MAJOR repercussions, since now an Umbrakinetic locked in a "completely" dark room will find themselves surprisingly unable to do anything!

Also, it could be any manipulation that would render photons unseen by us!
Converting all frequencies outside of our range of vision, pulling them all in, etc...

Answer (score 12):

### It's not because you can do it that you understand how you do it

As accurately explained in [JBH's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/235123/96713), you cannot really have a plausible "manipulation of the absence of light" without manipulating light itself. So here's my solution : your character does manipulate light, but thinks they're manipulating darkness.

You can explain it any way you want, be it directly manipulating photons, the atmosphere or anything. But your character doesn't need to know how it works. For them, they're creating and manipulating "darkness", whatever that means in their mind. Even if, in reality, they're manipulating light, the way they think about it makes it so that if anyone looks at the consequences of their ability, it's manipulating darkness.

It's actually a common trope to have a character not understand how their abilities work at the start, especially because it's a good setup for character evolutions. If they ever notice that they're actually manipulating photons, or simply get a better understanding of how their ability works, for instance by having someone versed in the topic explain it to them, it could lead to them learning new ways to use it, and with enough mind gymnastics on their end, add "manipulation of light" to their arsenal.

Comment: Maybe their power is controlled at an emotional level - they (subconsciously) loath bright light, so their brains automatically alter nearby photons to keep them from seeing light spots/beams close by.  A bit of practice lets them control the power to make "shadows" appear wherever they want.  Translating that to direct "light manipulation", however, would require them to acknowledge their own fears and gain a higher level of emotional control, with all the discipline & character development that implies.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica exactly the kind of interpretation I was thinking about. Opens up alot of interesting character developments. Especially since light manipulation can be opened up to a lot of interesting possibilities, if pushed far enough.

Answer (score 4):

First, +1 to JBH, that was my first thought.

If you converted the photonic energy to mass (via E=MC^2) the amount of mass would be miniscule. At best for the brightest light I imagine you'd be creating a few atoms of hydrogen.

However, the visible light spectrum of photonic vibration is quite narrow. Beneath it is infrared, above it is ultraviolet, and X-rays, etc.

An alternative to turning the photons into mass is just modifying their frequency, say reducing it to infrared. We cannot sense infrared as light; a room filled with infrared radiation is completely dark. But it is still the same photons. We do sense those as heat. If your character has a magical lensing effect, they could create a warm shell around something that shifts all visible light into the infrared band.

> EDIT due to comment: I wasn't clear on why this shell is warm. If we change the frequency of visible light to a lower frequency, the lower frequency has less energy. If we are not doing energy to matter conversion, then the excess energy has to go somewhere. It can go into warming atmospheric molecules at the point of the conversion. That would be a "shell" of where the darkness effect takes place. How, exactly, this reduction in frequency is accomplished is unexplained magic; but it a plausible physical consequence of reducing the the EM wave length, and thus reducing the energy of the photon.

That would result in darkness inside the shell. The area of conversion (where the 'shell' is) can be very warm air, if anybody passes through it, and the shell would be warmer on the inside than the surrounding air. And as far as somebody inside the shell, it would be dark in all directions, because no visible light reaches their eyes from anywhere. It might as well be black walls all around.

But if they tried to feel their way to the wall, presuming the shell does not move, then at some point they find the edge as hot air, and they can walk through it into the light.

If your hero turns it off, the warm air just dissipates, like dousing a campfire.

If you want, you can make the whole region frequency converting; a flashlight inside the sphere emits no light, it just emits an equivalent number of photons as infrared light. It will feel slightly warmer [edit: due to magical frequency downshifting], that's it. The same for fire; it will feel like fire and behave like fire, but it will be a bit hotter and completely dark.

If there is no light to sense, the sighted people and animals inside the bubble are effectively blind, they cannot see a thing.

Which leads you to another way to implement this; a biological suppression of signals on optic nerves. That would be fine on a personal level, but undetectable outside the bubble of influence. So it depends on what your story demands: I suspect you want want people outside the bubble to see the area of darkness; in that case go with photon frequency conversion to outside the visible spectrum.

Alternatively, if you just want people in a bubble to experience blindness but appear visible and normal to observers outside the bubble, you could go with optic nerve blocking; or preventing retinas from reacting to light.

Comment: Very warm air definitely doesn't change EM waves' wavelength, neither does a lens. You might be confusing refraction with photonic up/down conversion. The latter is more is more involved (and useless in this case because it always start with absorption, which is enough for your purposes; having an oaque layer all around does make your sphere dark). Very warm air does not make things look darker

Comment: @BarbaudJulien No, I am not. If we change the frequency of visible light to a lower frequency, the lower frequency has less energy. If we are not doing energy to matter conversion, then the energy has to go somewhere. It can go into warming atmospheric molecules at the point of the conversion. That would be a "shell" of where the effect takes place. How, exactly, this is done is unexplained magic; but it a plausible physical consequence of changing the EM wave length. I will edit and add this explanation to my answer.

Comment: you do not have to dissipate energy for down conversion. you can simply emit two photons of lower energy for one of higher energy. i invite you to google photonic down conversion.

Comment: But wouldn't that be going off track? I know light is radiation but it is the only radiation we can see, and it always associated with darkness unlike other radiation variants.

Comment: @PlanetJuice I'm not sure what you mean by "off track". If you want it to be dark in a region, you exclude *visible* light. But visible light carries energy, you need to either move that energy or convert it into something else. You might convert it into an electron or something, or you can do what real black matter does; it absorbs a visible frequency  photon at one frequency and converts that into particulate vibration (heat). I am suggest the same, your magic paper-thin shield absorbs visible frequency photons and converts them into vibration energy for air molecules (heat).

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

## The person can manipulate the properties of surfaces to minimize light reflection

There are scientific researches into [extreme black paints](https://mymodernmet.com/stuart-semple-black-paint/) and [extreme black coatings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack). We know that perceived blackness can be enhanced by manipulating the microscopic properties of surfaces.  Your character can do this.  Naturally because of how its approached, they think of it as manipulating darkness not light, whatever may physically be going on.

Note this won't prevent Infra red radiation, or transmission.  But most objects ate seen by their reflected light and this will kill that.  Light emission is then tackled by applying the same or appropriate  properties to the light bulb or other container, or at a  pinch the viewer's eyeball (!).

This doesn't cover every way they would need to create and manage darkness  selectively  but could probably be extended to do so?

Answer (score 3):

1. Darkness wielders are unknowingly wielding light. If you keep in mind that you could make a room dark by removing light, and that there is a spectrum of invisible light lengths, one amusing explanation of darkness powers is that "darkness" wielders just aren't aware of what they actually wielding - plus its an awesome plot moment when someone suddenly doubles the nature of their powers at a late point in the story.
2. Darkness users are actually manipulating space, photons go bye-bye. The physics thingy which carries light is known as a photon. Sometimes it behaves like a particle, sometimes it behaves like a wave. If you willing to say that when your "Darkness" wielders use their power the photons disappear in the affected area, then the abilities you describe could be explained by directly manipulating space.
3. Anti-light! When matter and anti-matter collide they completely annihilate each other, releasing an explosion of energy and photons. Photons can't be annihilated because they have zero charge (matter has positive charge, anti-matter negative charge) which means that "light" has no true opposite. If you pretend there is another property of particles, and that photons are positive in it, then you could invent a negative photon, meaning there would be a type of dark light which would annihilate photons (and light) on contact in addition to the darkness which is just the absence of light.

Comment: 1. I suppose it being a variation of light manipulation can make sense, especially if the outline or shape of the darkness is reinforced with light. 2. space would make even more sense and explain its ability to move matter. Maybe pair it up with 1.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple answer for you. Umbrakinesis can be performed by having an area repel light. Not block it, like with normal shadow, but bend light, like with prisms, so that it doesn't hit the spot the person is concentrating on.

You'll have to figure out how far out the spot redirects light, since the redirection point will look slightly brighter to the onlookers.

Comment: That would be a simply but easy way to make umbrakinesis possible

Comment: Thank you. I may have to use this myself some time.

Answer (score 1):

## Energy moves from areas of high concentration to areas of low concentration:

Your “Darkness” wielders are actually just wicking away power. They have some huge sink into which they can dump energy. So they can absorb the energy from photons to cause “darkness” or drain kinetic energy to dampen motion. If there are electronics, they can disable them by draining the energy from a current. Real masters can even drain heat to dampen fires or freeze liquids.

So their powers don’t so much do something as stop something else. The higher potential the energy in use, the easier it is to drain. If your magic system has a consistent energy form, then magic energy is drained, with the strongest Magic’s being the easiest to defeat.

The form of this vast sink is open to interpretation, but with pseudo magic, a parallel universe with incredibly low energy potential is a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Change the science of light in your universe. Here's one example approach.

Light and darkness are two immiscible, compressible fluids. Light flows out of sources, bounces off surfaces, etc. And darkness is a fluid but a very compressible one; it 'falls back' when it interacts with light. It's the weaker of the two fluids by far, but there's far more of it. [Nature abhor a vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horror_vacui_(physics)), and what nature puts into the vacuum is darkness.

The character can make darkness more robust. Under their control, darkness can push back light, or mix with it to create shade, increase it's viscosity to create effects like slowing, solidify it to create weapons, etc.

If you think of it as a kind of wind magic, it could make scientific sense.

You just need to drop the idea of photons and rays -- but a wave theory is still possible, it's just waves of aetheric darkess.

Comment: These ideas resemble 18th-19th century aether-based physics.. suppose it were true and applicable to this world, nice ideas.. but the challenge here is the "science based" tag. That means current physics !

Comment: @Goodies I disagree. Science-based is  "For questions that require plausible (better than suspension-of-disbelief) answers based on Real World science that are not necessarily constrained to the known limits of Real World science." We're talking about an alternate reality with different physics. Requiring it to comply with the rules of a different reality seems more like hard-science than science-based.

Comment: @barbecue I respect your opinion about tags, but "Real World science" is not the above. Light and darkness are radiation phenomena, no fluids.

Comment: @Goodies light and darkness are radiation phenomena in THIS world. In Terry Pratchett's Discworld, light is a fluid. You seem to be ignoring the whole "not necessarily constrained by the known limits" part.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can answer this question under this definition. Magic is impossible under current science, and in OP's question we already presuppose wizards; that calls for a huge change to the natural world, imposing new constraints like 'the minds of sentient can disrupt existing processes like the laws of thermodynamics'. Once you throw out basic thermodynamics, you aren't talking about anything like science. We're just talking about narrative flavour.

Answer (score 0):

## It's actually dust control.

They assume they are controlling shadows, but they are actually controlling dust particles in the air.

When they move objects with shadows, they are condensing dust into a ball which looks dark and can push things.

When they darken areas, they are forming blobs of condensed dust. They have the magic of small particle manipulation which tends to form darkness when they use it.

Comment: I don't exactly see how dust particles and shadows are exactly connected in this case.

Comment: Dust blocks light, so does shadow. Dust has substance, shadow does not.

Answer (score 0):

## Phased Light

(I'll elaborate on this answer more later)

Light is a particle but also a wave, and when two of the same waves 180 degrees out of phase overlap, they cancel out. This is the idea behind a lot of holographic technology in scifi universes.

If you had sufficient foreknowledge about the light entering a room, you could project the same amount of light at the precise time so that the two light fields are 180° out of phase everywhere within a particular region, creating a volume of darkness in an otherwise brightly-lit room.